# Can I use std::accumulate with a fallible operation without exceptions?

Tags: c++, stl

I have some operation that I would like to use with std::accumulate, but it may fail for some elements, in which case the accumulation should be aborted. With exceptions, I could throw an exception in case of failure, but I need to build without exceptions. With exceptions, this would look like this (the operation being greatly simplified):

```
std::optional<int> sum_accumulate_with_exceptions(
    std::vector<int> const& aVec) {
  try {
    return std::accumulate(aVec.begin(), aVec.end(), 0,
                           [](int oldSum, int current) {
                             if (current > 42)
                               throw std::logic_error{"too large"};
                             return oldSum + current;
                           });
  } catch (std::logic_error const&) {
    return std::nullopt;
  }
}
```

Actually, even with the possibility of using exceptions, this appears quite wasteful, as I am not interested in the particular exception thrown, and so the overhead of exceptions is unnecessarily large.

Using std::accumulate, I could use an error flag like this:

```
std::optional<int> sum_accumulate_without_exceptions(
    std::vector<int> const& aVec) {
  bool errored = false;

  int res = std::accumulate(aVec.begin(), aVec.end(), 0,
                            [&errored](int oldSum, int current) {
                              if (errored) return 0;
                              if (current > 42) {
                                errored = true;
                                return 0;
                              }
                              return oldSum + current;
                            });
  return errored ? std::optional<int>{} : res;
}
```

However, this is clearly bad, since this always iterates over the whole container, which might be large.

I came up with my own variant of std::accumulate:

```
template <typename It, typename T, typename Op>
std::optional<T> accumulate_shortcircuit(It aBegin, It aEnd, T aInit,
                                         const Op& aOp) {
  std::optional<T> res = std::move(aInit);

  for (auto it = aBegin; it != aEnd; ++it) {
    res = aOp(*res, *it);
    if (!res) break;
  }

  return res;
}
```

This can be used nicely for the example case like this:

```
std::optional<int> sum_accumulate_shortcircuit(std::vector<int> const& aVec) {
  return accumulate_shortcircuit(aVec.begin(), aVec.end(), 0,
                                 [](int oldSum, int current) {
                                   if (current > 42) {
                                     return std::optional<int>{};
                                   }
                                   return std::optional<int>{oldSum + current};
                                 });
}
```

However, I would prefer using std::accumulate (or any other standard library algorithm [edit:] or combination of them) itself, instead of using a replacement. Is there any way to achieve this?

While I was using C++17's std::optional in the example, ideally this would only use C++14 standard library algorithms, but I am also interested in solutions from newer/future standard versions.

[edit:] Based on @NathanOliver's answer, accumulate_shortcircuit could be implemented like this without having the range TS:

```
template <typename It, typename T, typename Op>
std::optional<T> accumulate_shortcircuit(It aBegin, It aEnd, T aInit,
                                         const Op& aOp) {
  std::optional<T> res = std::move(aInit);

  std::all_of(aBegin, aEnd, [&](const T& element) {
    return static_cast<bool>(res = aOp(*res, element));
  });

  return res;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you like your `accumulate_shortcircuit` option? The Standard Library is not intended to be exhaustive, it is ok to provide your own variants that follow the same practices.

Comment: Of course, it is not meant to be exhaustive, but I felt like this would be a common use case.

Comment: Why it is not option for you combining two algorithms 'filter' and 'accumulate', for example `remove_if` and `accumulate`. It might be done in lazy manner once you have ranges at hand.

Comment: @nicolai Of course, a combination of algorithms would also be great. remove_if wouldn't be appropriate however, as I don't want to skip the problematic entries, but break completely in that case. My example does not appear very good to me anymore, as, as opposed to my example, it would not be just a property of the input but an error during some complex transformation. The ranges TS seems to be a prerequisite for something that really fits my expectation.

Comment: "I file like this would be a common use case" -- the standard library is designed around the standard language. Using non-standard options (like no exceptions) may be common in some areas, but the standard library doesn't accommodate that.

Comment: @user2019765 Why do you want it to return an `optional`?  You pass in `aInit` so you will always be returning an initialized `optional`.  It doesn't gain you anything and cost you a tiny amount of resources.

Comment: @NathanOliver In case of an error, an uninitialized optional will be returned.

Comment: @PeteBecker Sure, but as I pointed out, even if you are generally using exceptions, in such a case, using exceptions is quite wasteful, since no properties of the exception (type, message) will be used.

Comment: @user2019765 The cost of constructing an exception object is trivial; it's the cost for propagating an exception (looking up the stack handling code) that matters.

Answer (score 4):

You need an algorithm that has short circuiting built in.  The first one that comes to to mind is [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).  You can use a lambda to do the sumation, and then return true to it once you've reached the point where you want to return.  That would give you a function like

```
int sum_accumulate_shortcircuit(std::vector<int> const& aVec) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    std::any_of(aVec.begin(), aVec.end(), 
                [&](auto elm) { if (elm > 42) return true; sum += elm; return false; });
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You're right, that would do it, and it would use some standard library algorithm like I wished for. It's not exactly what I imagined, as it it somewhat more generic/low-level than std::accumulate, but at least I could use std::any_of within my accumulate_shortcircuit.

Comment: To get the intended behavior, you need to write `if(std::any_of(...)) return std::null_opt;`

Comment: There https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of I cannot find guarantee in which order range is evaluated, am I missing something? If order is not defined then it is unusable in this case.

Comment: @Slava Interesting, I had thought that it was specified to be evaluated in order. However, the evaluation order is not actually relevant.

Comment: @user2019765 This is guaranteed to go in the forward direction from the start (`begin()`).  We know this because it uses input iterators and those are only single pass iterators.

Comment: Isn't the order defined by however the iterator operates from begin to end?  So it would be defined by the iterator sequence.

Comment: Ah this is what I am missing, iterator category.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, this type of composition of algorithms/operations will be much easier in C++20 (with the inclusion of the ranges TS). This is an example from the current TS using `accumulate` and `view::take_while`:

```
auto sum = ranges::accumulate(my_vec | view::take_while([] (auto i) -> i <= 42), 0);
```